# C++ local variable destruction order

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, local-variables

Is there a defined order in which local variables are deallocated in C++ (11) ?
To be more concise: In which order will side effects of the destructors of two local variables in the same scope become visible?

e.g.:

```
struct X{
  ~X(){/*do something*/}
}

int main(){
   X x1;
   X x2;
   return 0;
}
```

Is `x1` or `x2` destroyed first when main returns or is the order undefined in C++11?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Within each category of storage classes (except dynamically allocated objects), objects are destructed in the reverse order of construction.

Comment: What part of the C++ standard guarantees this order?

Comment: @DavidGrayson A different part for each category.  For objects with
thread-local or static storage, see §3.6.3.  For objects with auto
lifetime see §6.6 (which is _not_ where one might expect to look for
it). For class members and bases, see §12.4/8.  For temporaries, see
§12.2.

Comment: Temporaries do not strictly follow LIFO ordering, due to lifetime extension when a reference directly binds one.

Answer (score 32):

**I. About local variables**

1. Local variables are allocated on the *Stack*.
2. The *Stack* is based on a `LIFO` (`Last-In-First-Out`) pattern.
3. So variables are destroyed and deallocated in the reverse order of allocation and construction.

**II. About your example**

Your function `main()` is called:

- `x1` is allocated and constructed on the *Stack*,
- `x2` is allocated and constructed on the *Stack*

and when the end of the `main()` function scope is reached:

- `x2` is destroyed and deallocated from the *Stack*,
- `x1` is destroyed and deallocated from the *Stack*

**III. Moreover**

The *Stack* look like this:

(Behaviour of the *Stack* seems more understandable with a scheme)

[image: Stack scheme]

Comment: Although I don't disagree with the picture, the implementation is not pushing/popping anymore and that has been the case for ages. Instead it does one `sub %esp, <size>` and at exit it does `add %esp, <size>`. So in other words all the necessary space is allocated in one swoop (only `alloca()` will dynamically reduce the stack pointer further.)

Comment: This issue doesn't have anything to do with the existence of a stack or the direction in which things are allocated on it. It has to do with *lexical scopes* being abandoned in the reverse order of their establishment. The objects `x1` and `x2` can be allocated in the stack frame in any order.  Or even not at all; e.g. they can be empty structs.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Spooky! Comments in similar vein on answer from 2014 within seconds of each other.

Answer (score 8):

This is a `Stack Data Structure` behaviour, so local variables stores in Stack as `LIFO (Last-In-First-Out)` data structure, you can imagine that in a LIFO data structure, the last variable added to the structure must be the first one to be removed. variables are `removed` from the stack in the `reverse order` to the order of their addition.

Comment: Stacks are LIFO, not FIFO. (Queues are FIFO.)

Answer (score 4):

They are destroyed in reverse allocation order, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257768/local-variables-construction-and-destruction-with-optimizer-involved). In this case, this means that `x2` will be destroyed before `x1`.

Answer (score 3):

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#order-dtors-for-locals

isocpp.org has a FAQ about this topic and it says it does **in a reverse order**. I think that the official site didn't exist when this original question had been asked though.

Comment: Nice link. It provides short answers to a lot of destruction order related questions by an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2):

They will be destroyed following a reverse order of their construction.

Comment: Actually, in the reverse order of their construction.